# How to use java code to access MySQL DB in Jape grammar‏

Tags: gate

How can I use following codes in the RHS of a JAPE grammar?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
...
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url+DBName+addon,DBUser,DBPasswd);
...
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
ResultSet result;
result = statement.executeQuery();
```

I have refered to the user guide and add the following import at the very beginning of the file:

```
Imports:{
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
}
```

The error I saw in Message Tab is

```
Error: Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException at line 70 in japeactionclasses.instancespairActionClass28
Error: Unhandled exception type SQLException at line 80 in japeactionclasses.instancespairActionClass28
Error: Unhandled exception type SQLException at line 101 in japeactionclasses.instancespairActionClass28
....
```

line 70 is exactly:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

So, it seems that the java mysql connector is not found. How can I configure in Gate?  like adding the jar in building path under Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use [gate2mysql](https://code.google.com/p/gate2mysql/)  plugin? If this is not possible and you wish to use approach described above, please make sure that you put MySQL driver jar file in to **GATE classpath**.

Comment: GATE classpath?  would you please tell where is the file located?  thanks  I have added in the CLASSPATH of system environment variables, but doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I think connection jar is missing for mysql connection. Hopefully, adding the respective jar can solve this problem.